# Using a recursive method to determine if a word is elf-ish

Tags: java, recursion

```
public static boolean Xish
```

This method should take in two parameters, in the following order:  A String of the word to check and a String made up of the letters to check for. For example, a word is considered elf-ish, if it contains the letters e, l, and f, in any order `(“waffle”, “rainleaf”)` and a true return of the method would be `Xish(“waffle”, ”elf”)`. If there are multiple occurrences of a letter to check for, it must occur multiple times in the search word. Return true if the word contains all the needed characters and false if it does not contain all the characters.

This is what I have so far, but I am lost how I would recall the method and check to see if there are multiple occurrences (2nd part).

```
public static boolean Xish(String check, String letters) {
        String word = check;
        String contains= letters;

        if(word.indexOf(contains) >= 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

Comment: You could implement the multiplicity requirement as follows:  for every distinct letter `x` in `letters`, count the number of occurrences `N_x` in `letters`.  Count the number of occurrences of these same letters in `check`, and call this `M_x`.  Return true if `M_x >= N_x` for all `x` in `letters`.  Basically, you want to check if the multiset formed by `letters` is a subset of the multiset formed by the letters of `check`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, doing this recursively will also take care of the multiple occurrences issue.

First, your own method is not really correct - it looks for the whole `letters` in the word. That is, if `letters` is `elf`, then true will be returned for `self`, but not for `heartfelt`, and that's wrong. You are supposed to look for the individual letters, because the order is not important.

For recursion:

1. If the `letters` is an empty string - return true. You can say that any word is fine if there are no restrictions.
2. If the `check` is an empty string - return false. An empty string does not contain the letters in `letters` (and we already know that letters is not empty).
3. Take the first letter in `letters`. Look for it in `check`. If it's not there, return false.
4. If it was there, then call the same method, but pass only what remains of `check` and `letters`. For example, if `check` was `selfish` and `letters` was `elf`, you found that `e` exists. Return the result of `Xish("slfish","lf")`. This will take care of the multiple occurrences. You do that by using `substring` and concatenating the applicable parts.

If multiple occurrences weren't an issue, you could pass the `check` as-is to the next level of the recursion. But since they matter, we need to remove one letter for each letter requested, to make sure that we don't match the same position again for the next occurrenc.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean Xish(String check, String letters) {
    boolean ish = true;
    String word = check;

    char[] contains= letters.toCharArray();

    for(int i = 0; i < contains.length; i++){
        if(word.indexOf(contains[i]) < 0){
            ish = false;
        }else {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(word);
            sb.deleteCharAt(word.indexOf(contains[i]));
            word = sb.toString();
            // System.out.println(word);
        }
    }

    return ish;
}
```

This could be one way, but it is not recursive.
Xish("Waffle", "elff") returns true, but
Xish("Waffle", "elfff") returns false.

Comment: 0 is a valid index - the first letter in the word.

Comment: Good catch @RealSkeptic, I have removed that

Answer (score 0):

The title mentions a recursive function so I will propose a recursive solution.

1. For each character in your check string, compare it against the first character in your letters string.
2. If the compared characters are equivalent, remove the first character from your letters string and pass both strings back into your function.
3. If the check string is fully iterated without finding a character in the letters string, return false
4. If letters is empty at any point, return true

This is a brute force approach, and there are several other ways to accomplish what you are looking for. Maybe think about how you could check every character in your in you check string a single time?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether it solves your question 100 %. But i tried a recursive method. See if this helps.

package com.company;

public class Selfish {

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    String check = "waffle";
    String letters = "elf"; // "eof"

    int xishCount = xish(check, letters, 0);

    if(letters.length()== xishCount) {
        System.out.println("TRUE");
    }else{
        System.out.println("FALSE");
    }
}


static int xish(String check, String letters, int xishCount) {

    if(letters.length() < 1) {
        return 0;
    }

    if(check.contains(letters.substring(0, 1))) {
        xishCount = 1;
    }

    return xishCount + xish(check, letters.substring(1, letters.length()), 0);
}
```

}